# http_post_fields() fails after installing pecl_http

Tags: ubuntu, pecl, php

I just installed pecl_http with the default options and added the line "extension=http.so" to my active php.ini configuration file, but when I run my script I'm still getting

> Call to undefined function http_post_fields()

Any ideas on what I can check to fix the problem?

Here's the code:

```
    $url = "http://localhost/elistings/public/dynamicSearch.php";
    $data = array("phone_number" => "",
               "business_name" => "name",
               "business_address" => "my address",
               "city_and_state" => "city, CA",
               );

$response = http_post_fields($url, $data);
echo $response;
```

Comment: According to the manual page for **[http_post_fields](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-post-fields.php)** you need to have pecl_http version 0.10.0 or later. Which version did you install? Also, can you paste the code in question?

Comment: Not sure how to get the pecl_http version# - researching now

Comment: Not sure if **[phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)** will show version numbers for modules (I don't have access to a machine to try it right now), but you can try creating a script that looks like this: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Or, if you used apt-get to install pecl_http, you can do `apt-cache show pecl_http` to get more information about the package.

Comment: The module isn't even showing up in using phpinfo(), which makes sense with what I'm seeing. What would keep the module from getting loaded? I've added the "extension=http.so" line to the php.ini file that phpinfo() displays.

Comment: How did you install pecl_http? If you used apt-get, does it say that it's already installed when you try to install it? If you're on a 64-bit machine, did you install the 64-bit version instead of the 32-bit version (if available)? If you installed it from source, are you sure it installed successfully?

Comment: Also you have a stay comma after `"city, CA"`. That probably doesn't explain your error, but try removing that.

Comment: I am on a 64bit machine - I used "pecl install pecl_http" to install the module. Is there a 64 bit module with a different name that I need? BTW, the extra comma doesn't affect PHP code execution, and I always include it as a preventative measure in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After verifying that pecl_http was successfully installed, have you tried **[this](http://www.art122-5.net/index.php/How_to_install_PECL_HTTP)**?

> We have to activate the module, don't modify the file /etc/php.ini,
>   but add a file pecl_http.ini in /etc/php.d
>
> ```
> ; Enable pecl_http extension module
> extension=http.so
> ```
>
> restart Apache

Comment: I already tried something similar, although my "additional .ini files" directory is "/usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d"

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but it's working now I'll mark your reply as the answer to thank you for your help, but it wasn't what got things working. Nevertheless there's plenty of helpful info here for people with this kind of problem!

Comment: That's strange but good to hear. If you do end up figuring out what the problem was, you can always post an answer to your own question and mark it as the best answer (i.e. the best answer can be changed at any time). You won't get any rep points for doing so, of course.